# Is it possible to grant admin permissions via plugins through userPermissions->saveUserPermissions?

Tags: plugins, admin, permissions

I'd like to add admin privileges to a user I'm creating like so:

```
  if($user == null)
  {
    $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];

    $lastName = $_GET['lastName'];
    $userName = $firstName . $lastName;
    $user = new UserModel();

    $user->username   = $userName;
    $user->email      = $email;
    $user->firstName  = $firstName;
    $user->lastName   = $lastName;

    craft()->users->saveUser($user);

    $permissions = [HOW DO I SET ADMIN PERMS?]
    craft()->userPermissions->saveUserPermissions($user['id'], $permissions)

}
```

Comment: I don't know the context that you're doing this in, but needless to say, generally speaking be cautious in creating admins programatically.  Especially if it's a front-end request from untrusted input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
$user->admin = true;
```

That data is part of the UserModel, so be sure to add it before the `saveUser` call.

Being a full-blown admin not technically part of setting permissions. If the user is an admin, that supersedes all other permissions settings.